# WebRequest client certificate null on WebAPI side

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, openssl, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi controller action that I decorated with my `[x509Authorize]` attribute. I'm debugging this endpoint locally - and at the same time running a console application that tries to call this endpoint.

**Client side**

Here's the client code - slightly simplified:

```
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Temp\\ht-android-client.pfx");               
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44300/api/mobile/predict");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
....
```

I've asserted that the `Cert` is the correct certificate. I've installed the `.pfx` in my `CurrentUser\Personal` store and in the `LocalMachine\Personal` store - and modified to take the Cert from that store, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451024/webrequest-not-sending-client-certificate) but that doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var Cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "Android", true)[0];
```

**Server side**

And I'm listening on the WebAPI endpoint like with the following code:

```
public class x509AuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cert = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
       // value of 'cert' is null
```

I hit a breakpoint in the console app first - see that the correct certificate is selected. Then I hit the breakpoint on the server and see that the value of `.GetClientCertificate()` is `null`. What am I doing wrong? The other SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451024/webrequest-not-sending-client-certificate) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197762/webapi-httpclient-not-sending-client-certificate) didn't help me any further.

**Additional information on the certificates**

I've created a self-signed CA certificate which is installed on the `LocalMachine\Trusted root CA` store. I've created the android client cert - and signed it with my self-signed CA certificate. Then I converted that into a `pkcs12` file. This is the certificate that the client is using - which is also installed in my personal stores ( both machine and currentUser ) and is valid ( you can see the chain go back to the ROOT CA cert ).

Also - the certificate's purpose is set to clientAuth:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is indeed that the server needs to have the following set in the web.config in order to force IIS to start the SSL cert negotiation:

```
<security>
    <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
</security>
```

If this is not present - the certificate will be ignored and you will get `null` on the `GetClientCertificate()` call.

This implies however that *all* clients for my WebAPI are now forced to present a valid certificate - so my original idea of having just one controller method requiring a certificate does not seem possible.

Then there's the challenge of setting this config paramter in web.config, because of the restrictions for Azure Cloud Services. However - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148748/web-config-error-with-azure-emulator-iis-express-and-ssl-client-cert-authenticat) answer provides a solution for that.

**EDIT**

On a side note this is *not* supported [yet](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1095) in ASP.NET vNext ( v rc-01-final )

Comment: when i put this: <security>
    <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
</security> in web.config I get 500 internal server error, both on localhsot and dev server.

Comment: `SslNegotiateCert` does not force certificates.  That is `SslRequireCert`.