# SSl certificate details in Web.config of Rest Client C#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

In WCF or web services we add details of certificate in client credential tag as below:

```
<clientCredentials>
    <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" findValue="XYZ" />
</clientCredentials>
```

But how can we configure it in Rest Client Case where we just need to access a URI of RestFul service.?

Comment: what rest client are you using?

Comment: It  is a web API where I am accessing the URI using HttpWebRequest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451024/webrequest-not-sending-client-certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a client certificate to a web request like this.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier, "XYZ", true);
X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];

HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest();
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

Note: `WebRequest`is obsolete.

Try using HttpClient instead, which would look something like this

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier, "XYZ", true);
X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];

WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: but is there a way to  read the certificate details like store name , Location , value etc from  web.config ? I have to make the details configurable

Comment: yes, just pass them in using ConfigurationManager, or however you read your configuration file

Comment: Thanks  @Alex I was able to pass in store name and find value of a certificate but unable to configure it for find type and store location

Comment: store them as appSettings in your config file, then use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Comment: yes but can not pass the string values in X509Store constructor we can only pass a StoreLocation enum

Comment: So use Enum.Parse?!

Comment: Thanks @Alex yes that way we can  but was searching if there is another way for that as we do for WCF . anyways I will continue with this way

Comment: WCF is very different to web requests.

Comment: If this answer was helpful please up vote and mark as an answer